# R Caret Package error imputing data with Pre-Process function

Tags: r, classification, r-caret

I have a dataset (training - testing) with missing data and I would like to impute data before the classification.

I tried using the caret package and the function preProcess, I want to impute data using the predictor variable for the training set and impute data on the testing set only using the knowledge of the trainingset without using the predictor of the testing set (that I should not know).

```
p = preProcess(x = training, method = "knnImpute", k = 10)
pred = predict(object = p, newdata = training)
pred1 = predict(object = p, newdata = testing)
```

when I run this code, I have this error on the second line

```
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 
  cannot impute when all predictors are missing in the new data point
```

I also tried to remove the predictor variable in the training set but the result is the same. I tried using the Iris dataset, removing some value in each column and removing the predictor and it works...but the datasets are with the same characteristics, both data.frame and both only with numeric values.

Comment: Providing a reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo` will help get your question answered.

Answer (score 1):

From your words ("without using the predictor of the testing set (that I should not know)"), I conclude that by "predictor" you mean the target variable - which is by itself a mistake. "Predictors" are the known features, from which we wish to predict the target variable...

If I am correct, you are actually trying to predict the target variable using missing values imputation, which is again a mistake, and not the purpose of missing value imputation. The correct use is when you have *some* (but not all) values missing from your predictors (features), and you want to imputate them in order, say, to be used as input to some ML algorithm which does not tolerate missing values.

Comment: I think that i just used the wrong terminology...my apologies.
First step: I have a dataset divided in training and testing, now I want to impute the missing data in the FEATURES (Predictors?) of the trainingset using the complete knowledge LABEL (target) + known FEATURES. (of course I have no missing data in the target). 
Second step: I want to impute the missing data in the testset (without using the target), but if I use the previous model "p" in the above example it tell me that is not of the same dimension (because the target column is not in the dataset).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error and have worked it out that the data set that you are imputing i.e. training, was created using createDataPartition by splitting into training and testing sets. Imputing works fine if you apply it to the original set before the split.

Comment: While doing this may allow the procedure to work, it is not advisable. Please see this cross-validation answer for more: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95083/imputation-before-or-after-splitting-into-train-and-test  TLDR: When we split first (before imputation procedures, etc.) we are attempting to emulate real life conditions. If you don't split first and instead impute across the whole data set then you run the risk of the appearance of better results than you'll observe in real life.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I traced the problem to using the target column as the trainRowNum  variable for the createDataPartition. When I did that, It raised the error

`Error in quantile.default(y, probs = seq(0, 1, length = groups)): 
  missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE`

and proceeding further with knnImpute and Predict gave the following error

`Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 
  cannot impute when all predictors are missing in the new data point`

So instead of using the target column, I created an Index variable

`x$Index <- as.numeric(rownames(x))`

and used the Index column for data partitioning as train dataset. It worked well and no error. The Index column can later be removed from the train dataset for further computation. I think that using column with missing variables for data partition leads to this kind of problem.